# How to transfer data from USB OTG to internal storage?

Tags: android, usb, storage, file-transfer, android-storage

I have developed an application which detects OTG USB using USBHOST, Till now I am getting a proper response. In the response, i am getting device id, path, class, subclass, vendor id. Now I need to transfer files which are available in USB OTG to Internal storage. Kindly let me any idea to transfer a file from USB OTG to internal storage in Android.

Comment: @greenapps could you please let me about question, is my idea was wrong or Thanks in advance is wrong

Comment: If you know the path then what do you need more?

Comment: `Using path we can transfer in all mobiles, `??? Sorry. Dont understand a word of this.

Comment: Sorry, using path we cant transfer in all different variant mobiles @greeenapps

Comment: And you did not give an example of such a path. Any reason not to give better information?